# converting merge function created using Object.entries.reduce into typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a merge function, which merges 2 objects at 2 levels deep (can be up to n-level but for me, I needed only two) of objects.

```js
const merge = (a, b) => {
    return Object.entries(a).reduce((agg, [key, value]) => ({
        ...agg,
        [key]: {
             ...agg[key],
            ...value,
        }
    }), b)
}
```

So if I have

```js
const a = {
  'key1': {
    'a1': 1,
  },
   'key2': {
    'a2': 1,
  }
}

const b = {
  'key1': {
    'b1': 1,
  },
   'key3': {
    'b3': 1,
  }
}
merge(a, b)
```

The output will be 
`{ key1: { b1: 1, a1: 1 }, key3: { b3: 1 }, key2: { a2: 1 } }`

I created an interface which is very similar to `Object.assign`.

```js
interface Merge<T, U>{
    (a: T, b: U): T & U
}
```

and merge function

```
const merge: Merge<MyState, MyState> = (a, b) => {
    return Object.entries(a).reduce((agg, [key, value]) => ({
        ...agg,
        [key]: {
            ...(agg[key]), // Assuming it is always object
            ...value,
        }
    }), b)
}
```

I am getting 2 errors

1. On the line `...agg[key]`

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'MyState'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MyState'.ts(7053)
```

2. On the next `...value`

```
Spread types may only be created from object types.ts(2698)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: First of all - change `Object.keys(a)` to `Object. entries(a)`

Comment: That was typo, I was trying to do some workarounds.

Comment: Why use `reduce` for this? There is no need to create a whole new object and copy everything across on each iteration.

Comment: Immutability is something I keep as the core of everything I write, creating a new object is a relatively inexpensive operation while you pass an object to a function and the function modifies and it there would be a lot of side-effects for that. So I would prefer to keep the code immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be hard to make this *type safe*, because TypeScript can't really handle the higher-order type operation whereby the callback adds a single property to the return value each time it is called and ends up returning a value of type `T & U`.  The first call to the callback will have `agg` of type `U` and return `U & Pick<T, K>` for some singleton `K extends keyof T`, and the last call to the callback will have `agg` of type `U & Omit<T, L>` for some other singleton `L extends keyof T` and return `T & U`.  It could be a fun exercise to see how close we could get, but it's far easier and more productive to just say: verifying the type safety of this function is above the compiler's pay grade.

On the other hand, it should be easy enough to use some judicious [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler what types it should expect:

```
const merge = <T extends Record<keyof T, object>, U extends Record<keyof U, object>>(
  a: T, b: U
) => {
  return (
    Object.entries(a) as Array<[keyof T, T[keyof T]]>
  ).reduce((agg, [key, value]) => ({
    ...agg,
    [key]: {
      ...agg[key],
      ...value,
    }
  }), b as T & U)
}
```

Here I've used two assertions.  The first is that `Object.values()` will return an `Array<[keyof T, T[keyof T]]>`, which is more or less true; each element of the array will be a pair of keys and values of `T`.  The second is that `b` and therefore `agg` is `T & U`.  This is pretty much false but eventually becomes mostly true.  I say "mostly" because spread operators only approximately behave like intersections, especially when you have optional properties or primitive types, so proceed at your own risk.  Anyway asserting `b` to be `T & U` also implies that `merge()` returns `T & U`, which is what you want.

Also note that I've constrained `T` and `U` to be `object`s that hold `object`s, so that you don't accidentally use `merge()` where spreading two layers deep would be a mistake:

```
merge({ a: "" }, { a: { b: 1 } }); // error!
//      ~ <-- string is not object
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgMID2IAzmFAK64FTIDeAsAFDLIThTATEA8AKgHwAKAgC46yANrExpDiADmAXTG9kAX2QAfZAEEoUOAE8AMsADWEPvwCUYqWVDyANMl6KJigNxMWbB12ExWjVbSVlHFzgQQ3cvJjUmJgQiUmQYAgJkAF5kPhcAVRcAaVYAD0gQABNiZAtDAhhXF2MyiuraiHrGgUEfZDh5eTF85AAyZAAFYAQzPOQi-jHJuCgwYDgAG24pmbnjfn4XCTqXADdN8ghlSWMXXgljRUVrbMXe5hZxADofgedJOrXWjIH5fP7HTqKFyg84bS7qdQvOA1EbjHazXjFLTIfaJRjJEhgZAAW2g8hQOT4rTY7QASjhqJVuHUGk1kAQsDgwIdkCMIOUaTV6ckoEyWY1CuzObgDu8WHAVC50MMmC8sosGB8oBAwOQoCBkHLPhhsLgvn4OAE4EianoDIZuBCumz7uLXE9+H1rF9tZVKBBBII-kcTshYZdnq9DZrPiDfoMnH0WE6gUnPqDwYDEx9YzCLhBs7GNH0Qkr+jVVON8tZ4njSVByYJgQrkAAiVvqFzNoLIZXIACMCJCnmQAHpR6x9NQAIRMcexlgAP1yAFoV8hwgpkMAaiACESOaawHikikiXBsnQ+gByOr969BNPXuD3sT9wudm91ABMD6vOeQZ9fzfD8EkYMDT0JXtLxjQC7z-WCWGvdBXwHUCP1vToAGYEKfdAcJAkta0YSDUjgdBL3rRs4CVaxvBIhiawYpggA)